# SQLException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Time using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a object and I created it by using **Hibernate Reverse Engineering Wizard** and **Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs From Database**.

In this case my table has a sql time field(**reminder_time**), but hibernate generated the field as java.util.Date field .

This is my table,

[image]

The mentioned field is reminder_time.

This is my object,

```
import java.util.Date;


public class Reminder  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer idreminder;
     private Patient patient;
     private String remindAbout;
     private Date reminderTime;
     private Date reminderDate;
     private boolean active;
     private boolean repeat;
     private Date dateCreated;
     private Date lastUpdated;

    public Reminder() {
    }


    public Reminder(Patient patient, String remindAbout, Date reminderTime, Date reminderDate, boolean active, boolean repeat, Date lastUpdated) {
        this.patient = patient;
        this.remindAbout = remindAbout;
        this.reminderTime = reminderTime;
        this.reminderDate = reminderDate;
        this.active = active;
        this.repeat = repeat;
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }
    public Reminder(Patient patient, String remindAbout, Date reminderTime, Date reminderDate, boolean active, boolean repeat, Date dateCreated, Date lastUpdated) {
       this.patient = patient;
       this.remindAbout = remindAbout;
       this.reminderTime = reminderTime;
       this.reminderDate = reminderDate;
       this.active = active;
       this.repeat = repeat;
       this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
       this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }

    public Integer getIdreminder() {
        return this.idreminder;
    }

    public void setIdreminder(Integer idreminder) {
        this.idreminder = idreminder;
    }
    public Patient getPatient() {
        return this.patient;
    }

    public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
        this.patient = patient;
    }
    public String getRemindAbout() {
        return this.remindAbout;
    }

    public void setRemindAbout(String remindAbout) {
        this.remindAbout = remindAbout;
    }
    public Date getReminderTime() {
        return this.reminderTime;
    }

    public void setReminderTime(Date reminderTime) {
        this.reminderTime = reminderTime;
    }
    public Date getReminderDate() {
        return this.reminderDate;
    }

    public void setReminderDate(Date reminderDate) {
        this.reminderDate = reminderDate;
    }
    public boolean isActive() {
        return this.active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    public boolean isRepeat() {
        return this.repeat;
    }

    public void setRepeat(boolean repeat) {
        this.repeat = repeat;
    }
    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return this.dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }
    public Date getLastUpdated() {
        return this.lastUpdated;
    }

    public void setLastUpdated(Date lastUpdated) {
        this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
    }
}
```

When I tried to save some data in to this table using above object, I got following exception,

```
Oct 06, 2016 4:40:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'repeat, date_created, last_updated) values (3, 'Taking medicine', '15:30:18', '2' at line 1
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

Have any ideas about this ?

Comment: Your title has nothing to do with the question, please fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repeat` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) and needs to be escaped by backticks or use a different column name.

Comment: You mean change the column name of database table by it self?

Comment: I mean choose another name than `repeat`.